# Issue with <link href hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, hyperlink

I'm beginning with this whole coding thing (it's beautiful) but I just found myself with an issue.

There's landing page I found and I kind of copied, it has a button that works as a hyperlink to another page but instead of that button, I have the code for a style sheet, it's kind of like a form people have to fill. So you press the button and the form pops out.

I have the code of the original landing page and I also have the code for the form but I don't know how to blend them, please help.

The first one is the original button code that takes people to https://myimstrategy.com/50perday-2/. I want to replace that site for a form that pops out. That's the second code in the bottom, I don't know how to merge both codes. I attached an image of the original button. I don't want to delete it, I just want the form to pop out when I click on it.

Thank you very much for your help!

```css
.el-content{
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 894px;
  min-height: 114px;
}
.ib2-button {
  color: rgb(15, 15, 15);
  background-color: rgb(25, 202, 6); 
  border-color: rgb(0, 174, 0); 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  text-shadow: rgb(147, 138, 138) 1px 1px 0px; 
  background-image: none;
  min-width: 920px; 
  min-height: 123px; 
  width: auto; 
  height: auto; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="el-content">
  <a href="https://myimstrategy.com/50perday-2/" class="ib2-button open-popup" target="_self">Claim Your Spot Now &gt;&gt;</a>
</div>
<link href="//app.webinarjam.net/assets/css/register_button.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div style="margin:auto;width:300px;">
  <div class="embedded-joinwebinar-button">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default css3button" title="regpopbox_35246_b21043f77c">
      <span>Register now</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//app.webinarjam.net/assets/js/porthole.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript" async></script>
<script src="//app.webinarjam.net/register.evergreen.extra.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript" async></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a popup, you're going to want to use javascript. 
This is typically referred to as a modal. Here is a link to a tutorial: [How TO - CSS/JS Modal](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap modal, or add `onclick="showForm()"`
And then you put `id="form"` to the form. Then in the head tag put

```
<script>
function showForm(){
    document.getElementById("form").style.display = "inline-block"; //It must have display: none, the form, and this will make it display
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find your image but I got it, you want to show a pop on a button click. You can simply provide a href like below:

```
<link href="jsFunctionName()" class="buttonClass">Open Form</link>
```

And try using jquery dialogue on link clicked via jquery. https://jqueryui.com/dialog/
e.g.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function jsFunctionName() {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
  } );
</script>

<div id="dialog" title="My Form">
  <form>
  </form>
</div>
```